# Changing the Source of an Image in XAML through C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, grid

So I have a Grid name Game (the main game board) what I wanna do is load every image from inside the grid when the program loads

```
foreach(Image myImage in Game.Children)
            {
                BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
                bi3.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SmallLogo.png");
                myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                myImage.Source = bi3;
            }
```

I am using this foreach but I always get error messages. I tried a lot of different methods but none worked so far. I am trying to make a matching memory game.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'.

Answer (score 0):

The child of your Grid is a StackPanel, not the Image itself. You'll probably need to dig in deeper to the StackPanel. If you share your XAML too it'll be easier to tell, but I'm guessing the Images are something like the datacontext of the one of the contents in your StackPanel.

Share the XAML if you're still running into issues

Answer (score 0):

After checking XAML you provided on jack's answer the problem is pretty obvious. You are iterating over all of the children of the Grid and implicitly casting them to Image but one of the child is a StackPanel and that is where your exception occurs. You should first check if that children is the Image:

```
foreach (var child in Game.Children)
{
    var myImage = child as Image;
    if (myImage == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
    bi3.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SmallLogo.png");
    myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    myImage.Source = bi3;
}
```

Comment: Better get all Image children by `foreach (var image in Game.Children.OfType<Image>())`.

Comment: Also I have another question I am quite new to Universal Apps, about the Uri Paths. Let's say that I have the image I want at C:\Users\Thanos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Assets\name.png does the ms-appx:///Assets/name.png work and find automatically the image I want?

Comment: @Clemens I tried putting what you said and it worked perfectly!! Also Endrus Thank you a lot as well! Your worked as fine!!